# Access app Documents folder from Today Extension

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

I have successfully shared data between my App and its Today Extension via userDefaults, but I am having trouble when it comes to actual files located in the app's Documents folder.

When I use this code in my app:

```
var documentsDir:NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
```

it returns:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/296494AA-946C-40E0-8646-F0895E131DCB/Documents/
```

but in the extension it returns:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/AB484342-537A-4CE7-9EF3-F2CAE352C8A3/Documents/
```

and obviously, the files are not there.

I read somewhere that I should use:

```
let containerURL = manager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.company.app")
let filePath = containerURL.path
```

but it returns:

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CD7CF610-EB5F-4246-8D30-D7F8BFA6A219
```

which didn't work either.

How can I get my iOS 8 Today Extension to read its container app's files located in Documents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can't access the documents folder of the containing app from extension.

But you can create a shared container that can be accessed by the containing app and all its extension.

You are on the right track using containingURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier. You just have to use that in both the app and the extension. It does not access the documents folder, but another container.

If you are updating an existing app that has been storing data in documents folder, you will need to move the data to the s8-today-extension

Check out this link.
http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/

Comment: The link doesn't have anything about using a shared container on disk. It uses NSUserDefaults.

Comment: You can only create a shared App Groups for extensions in watchOS <2